# Reconstructing a formset

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.10.

Studying formsets. Interested in method `has_changed`.

Trying to learn by analogy with forms: "When the form is submitted, we reconstruct it and provide the original data so that the comparison can be done" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed).

So, at the server we need to save initial data. Then Django renders html: a form is solitary,  our formset being just input tags with special ids. User submits the form. We catch `request.POST`.

Here we have to recunstruct the formset.

The problem is that being submitted, the formset looks like this:

```
QueryDict: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['X5RMIXfwfQH9zUYz7ODw59UPEr1AQaeciJR2qrLU64ipbBnbu4jKEcW0nVc019vC', 'X5RMIXfwfQH9zUYz7ODw59UPEr1AQaeciJR2qrLU64ipbBnbu4jKEcW0nVc019vC'], 'form-0-pub_date': ['2016-01-01'], 'form-1-pub_date': [''], 'form-0-title': ['Initial title'], 'form-1-title': ['']}>
```

To the best of my ability, I only can think of:

1.
Getting keys:

```
request.POST.keys()
```

Result:

```
dict_keys: dict_keys(['csrfmiddlewaretoken', 'form-0-pub_date', 'form-1-pub_date', 'form-0-title', 'form-1-title'])
```

2.
 splitting the keys like str.split('-'). Then I'll have somehow handle the data.

```
def post(self, request):
    l = list(request.POST.keys())
    l.remove("csrfmiddlewaretoken")
    for element in l:
        sp = element.split("-")
    pass
```

Well, this is all cumbersome. And I feel clumsy. So clumsy that I don't even know whether there is a practical value in the `has_changed` method.

Could you suggest me an elegant way to reconstruct a formset.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. It is written further in the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

```
ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
```